# set the kafka row key using nestjs transporter

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs

I had some great results using NESTJS Kafka transporter. The messages get nicely serialized and saved in the topic under the value attribute. i.e. value.id = 0, value.name = "John Does", value.topup="10", etc.

Using the nestjs proxy client, how do I set the key (and not only the value) of a message?

```
this.client.emit<string>('userevents', JSON.stringify(event));
```

In the method signature I don't see any parameter that could facilitate my need to set the key.

How did you guys do it? thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

NestJS official website does not state how we can put the key (for partition) with `client.emit`. It takes me some time to figure this out:

```
await this.client.emit('TOPIC_NAME',{
  key: 'your-key',
  value: { test: 123 },
});
```